# Read multiple lines STDIN Java

Tags: java, stdin

i need to read multiple lines from stdin in java.
For example i need to read this two lines:

```
A A A H
A E D A H
```

and give an answer for each line.
I have made this but i can stop the while

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    
Posicao p;
int max[][] = new int[4][], j = 0;
String com;
String[] b;
char[] c;

       while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            p = new Posicao();
            com = sc.nextLine();
            b = com.split(" ");
            c = new char [b.length];
            for(int i = 0;i<b.length;i++) c[i] = b[i].charAt(0);            
            p.comando(c);
            max[j++] = p.retorna();
        }
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, because my test cases are in a file and this way scanner can detect if there is next line or not.

Comment: This question is poorly written: "but i can stop the while"? You meant "can't", didn't you? Please fix the typos and give your question a better title like "How to stop reading lines from stdin in Java?"

Answer (score 0):

```
if (com.isEmpty()) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check what the user inputs and exit on empty input or the word "exit":

```
/*This would go in your while loop, after you process the input*/


      if (com.equals("") | com.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Exiting...");
            break;
        } else
            System.out.println("Still in loop");
```

Comment: This could work but i need to read this lines only and exit the program.

Comment: Read what lines? Under what conditions do you want to stop reading?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to modify this part `while(sc.hasNextLine())` to break the loop. Do you know any of the below values?

- Number of lines
- Any special char using which you can find end of input

Comment: I don't know the number of lines, the only thing i know is that every line ends with a H. I need to paste this two lines ant stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Read each line using Scanner.nextLine() method and use String.split() or StringTokenizer to read tokens from each line. (see the example below) :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] tokens = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
    }

    scanner.close();}
```